# php update query with order

Tags: php, mysql

please i am having issues concerning the order of records after updating.
I have two pages `home.php` and `settings.php`.
 The `home.php` contains result from a mysli select query.

```
 $getid = $getdata['user_id'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE `user_id` = ' $get_id' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15 ");
```

The records being selected are `id` `username` `notes` `date_added`, these records are successfully displayed in  `desc` order.

On my `settings.php` i'm allowing the user to update their username,while updating their username,i also run a update query that change the username on the `notes` table. New username are successfully updated both on the `user` table and `notes` table. But the unfortunate things is,when i get back to the `home.php` , the notes are not displayed in `desc` order again. it is displaying the notes from the top of the table.

The update query function(called from the `settings.php`):

```
 function update_user($update_data){
$con = db();
global $session_user_id;
$update= array();
array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');
foreach ($update_data as $field => $data) {
    $update[] = '`'. $field . '` =\''.$data .'\'';
}
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `users` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . , " WHERE `user_id` = '$session_user_id'");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE notes SET username = (SELECT `username`FROM  users WHERE user_id = $session_user_id) WHERE user_id = $session_user_id ");}
```

I have tried ordering by `date_added`, it's not working still.
Kindly help me out, thanks.

Comment: @user2860957 timestamp

Comment: Your sample code has the expression `' $get_id'` in it. That will require the actual value to include a space, which is probably not your intention. Also, you _really_ don’t need to include the back-ticks around your field names. That is a MySQL artifact, and normally a waste of space. It is only required if you have tricky field or table names.

Comment: For real trouble shooting, (a) include `print "SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE `user_id` = '$get_id' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15 ";` and (b) execute the statement in the SQL tab of PHPMyAdmin, or what command line tool you have access to.

Comment: @user2860957 updating the username from the users table